# How to trigger checkbox click event even if it's checked through Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, dom-events

I have many checkboxes in my page and there is a select all checkbox which checks all the checkboxes. Somehow I want to emulate that click event of checkbox even if it's checked/unchecked through select all button. How can I do it?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `.trigger()` method. See http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

E.g.:

```
$('#foo').trigger('click');
```

Comment: You can also just call `$('#foo').click()`, which effectively does the same thing.

Comment: How to do this with pure JavaScript?

Comment: appears `trigger('click')` toggles the current value.  If you want to just set it then set `checked` to true then call triggerHandler(...) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268222/jquery-checking-a-checkbox-and-triggering-javascript-onclick-event

Comment: How exactly do posts like this get marked as correct when they require using a 3rd party? He did not ask for a jQuery solution.

Comment: @Wancieho The question is tagged 'jquery'.

Comment: @Wancieho jQuery is javascript and it was not explicitly forbidden to use a 3rd party library solution. Hence the answer is a valid solution. Furthermore, jQuery is a very widespread library so many people with the same question will benefit from the answer. Finally, by pointing to a working solution the OP can dig deeper and check what jQuery is doing to come up with an own implementation.

Comment: @mihca firstly JavaScript !== jQuery. jQuery is a library written in JavaScript. Furthermore, I know it's widespread (yet fading away with the introduction of JS frameworks). I originally responded based on the fact that I didn't see the tag which Mark pointed out. I myself was looking for a pure JS solution for Angular and stumbled upon this question. To include jQuery to perform 1 operation is ludicrous but as I've said in this instance I missed the jQuery tag so the answer is valid.

Answer (score 18):

Getting check status

```
var checked = $("#selectall").is(":checked");
```

Then for setting

```
$("input:checkbox").attr("checked",checked);
```

Comment: Not tried this with `attr` as I use `prop` nowadays, but this method only checks the boxes, it does not fire the click event for each afterwards

Answer (score 10):

You can use `.change()` function too

E.g.:

```
$('form input[type=checkbox]').change(function() { console.log('hello') });
```

Comment: This does not work for me when the checkbox change is done through Javascript.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use this, I hope you can serve them.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#elements input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="elements">
  <input type="checkbox" id="item-1" value="1"> Item 1 <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="item-2" value="2" disabled> Item 2 <br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="item-3" value="3" disabled> Item 3 <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="item-4" value="4" disabled> Item 4 <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="item-5" value="5"> Item 5
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

no gQuery

document.getElementById('your_box').onclick();

I used certain class on my checkboxes.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("box_class");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i].checked) x[i].checked = false;
    else x[i].checked = true;
    x[i].onclick();
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

Trigger function from jQuery could be your answer.

[jQuery docs says:](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)
*Any event handlers attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the .trigger() method. A call to .trigger() executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user*

Thus best one line solution should be:

```
$('.selector_class').trigger('click');

//or

$('#foo').click();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  $("#gst_show>input").change(function(){

    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    if($("#gst_show>input:checkbox").attr("checked",checked)){
      alert('Checked Successfully');
    }

  });
```

Comment: CAN U EXPLAIN YOUR CODE

Comment: i call spaghetti on this one