# alert on check selector jQuery

Tags: jquery

Please advise on why the alert is not working, I have tried several methods and it still wont alert when the checkbox is being checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.classname').on('change', function(){ 
    if(this.checked) 
    {
    alert("hello world");
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.classname').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        alert("hello World"); 
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="classname"> 1st method

<input type="checkbox" id="classname2"> 2nt method
```

Can anyone please tell me where I went wrong or what I missed?

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in a snippet?

Comment: share HTML of your checkbox.

Comment: no console errors... please see snippet above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger checkbox click event even if it's checked through javascript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780912/how-to-trigger-checkbox-click-event-even-if-its-checked-through-javascript-code)

Comment: You use ` $('.classname')` on both functions **and** attribute ids to your inputs `#classname`  and `#classname2` whis are `id`s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is pretty simple.
You used the class selector instead of the id selector.

Make sure that you add the same class to both the checkboxes for it to function correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.classname').on('change', function(){ 
    if(this.checked) 
    {
    alert("hello world");
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.classname').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        alert("hello World"); 
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="classname"> 1st method

<input type="checkbox" class="classname"> 2nt method
```

Comment: yeah, i noticed it in the fiddle

Comment: This is backwards...change html to class so it works on both checkboxes

Comment: It triggers the alert twice.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, that's because both the approaches demonstrated in the original question work. Therefore , both conditions are triggered. The author is free to use whichever method he or she wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="classname">
```

set `class` attribute of your checkbox. you have set your `id` attribute instead. Your `jquery` selector (`.classname`) is for `class`

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet, your checkboxes have **id** `classname` instead of `class`.
You need either to use id in your selector, or add a class to your checkboxes.

**Working demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.classname').on('change', function(){ 
    if(this.checked) 
    {
    alert("hello world");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="classname"> 1st method
<input type="checkbox" class="classname"> 2nt method
```

Comment: Same method on both checkboxes.... Method is a big word... Try an example with 2 diff. mesg. I'm sure that's what OP wants.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It is just a demo. The OP can modify this method according to his needs. For me, it seems like the OP wanted the single method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.classname').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("hello World"); 
    }
  });
});
```

You cannot use this.check because checked is not the attribute.

You can try above code.

Comment: No. It is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".classname").change(function() { 
    if(this.checked) { 
        alert("hello world");
    } 
});
```

You can use "this.checked" to access the DOM element rather than wrapping the element up as a jQuery element and then calling some jQuery methods to achieve want you need. This method should also be faster than using the jQuery $(this) as well.

You must make sure that your check boxes have the "classname" class as well.